# How to redirect all network traffic to a VM or docker image?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, docker

I have a problem. I am running a wifi network. I would like to redirect ALL traffic on this network to a server. It would be nice if it was possible to use a docker container. It is not a problem to have a router connected directly to the host via the ethernet jack as I in that case can bridge the network.

So my question is:
Is it possible for all network traffic on a network (internal) to go to a VM or docker image? The VM or docker container will run either apache or Nginx.

And if so, How do I do this? preferably a kinda detailed guide.

I appreciate all answers!

Comment: From your description it is clear what you are trying to achieve. However, since there are multiple ways to achieve this its important to know why you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve finally?

Comment: @jvda What i am trying to achive in the end is for everyone that connects to the network a portal where they can login will appear. After this login i will develop something that will give them network access.